# Blocked Audio / Video Recording in Outlook web Add-in Chrome M64

Tags: outlook, office-js

A recent change in Chrome has caused camera and microphone use to be blocked in the Outlook web Add-in.

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-permissions-in-cross-origin-iframes

With this change the recording permissions need to be explicitly set in the parent iframe, which is controlled by Microsoft.

Is there any way to add the following attribute to the Outlook web Add-in iframe?

`allow="microphone; camera"`

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue we will begin investigating a fix.

Comment: Thanks for your patience, we are still investigating the fix.

Comment: Hello! Is it possible to get the microphone input in Web Add-ins?

Comment: Any updates on if this will get fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add-ins in Outlook on the Web support the following now:

`allow-"geolocation; microphone; camera"`

The change may take a couple weeks to become generally available to users.